# Print Writer does corrupt files when its used to upload files to a server

Tags: java, servlets, printwriter

Good Evening, today i faced a strange situation when i used Print Writer in uploading files to a server, the file is transferred i tried to use `FileOutPutStream` instead and it solves the problem, my question is why `PrintWriter` does that strange behaviour, here's the code that i used in uploading a file and save it at the server:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException{
int i;
if(request instanceof MultipartWrapper){

String DestinationPath="C:\\";
MultipartWrapper request1=(MultipartWrapper)request;
File f=request1.getFile("photo");
java.io.FileInputStream fis=new java.io.FileInputStream(f);
//PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(DestinationPath+f.getName()); causes the problem mentioned above  
java.io.FileOutputStream out=new java.io.FileOutputStream(DestinationPath+f.getName());
while((i=fis.read())!=-1){
out.write(i);
}
fis.close();
out.close();


}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between Writers and OutputStreams.  `PrintWriter.write(int)` is writing a *character*, while `FileOutputStream.write(int)` is writing a *byte*.  you were accidentally converting bytes to characters, which was corrupting your file.  in general, when just copying streams around, you want to stick to bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`PrintWriter` will create a Writer using the default encoding, while FileOutputStream will simply write raw bytes out. Provided that your original content and the server side use the same encoding, you won't have problems writing bytes and reinterpreting them. However, when you use the `PrintWriter`, the default system encoding is used, potentially mucking up your data.

Comment: regardless of the encoding used, reading bytes and writing them as chars will be broken (except maybe a single-byte encoding).

Comment: @jtahlborn I haven't seen OP's server side code, but he might be reading bytes on the server side as well

Comment: server side doesn't matter.  if the client side default encoding is multi-byte, the data will be borked before it leaves the client (or if the single-byte encoding changes certain invalid chars).

Comment: Ok, I'm missing something then. If I write the bytes of a String out (in whatever encoding they happened to be) and on the other side read the bytes into a `byte[]` and then decode them on the server side using `public String(byte[] bytes)` *and* the default encoding is ascii, won't I get the data out right? I know we are disgressing from OP's original question here ;)

Comment: as i said, if the client side default encoding was a single-byte encoding which didn't replace invalid chars, then it would "work" (hence your example with "ascii", which is single-byte, although i think the java ascii encoding is 7bit, not 8bit, so would probably still cause corruption).  what the server did is irrelevant (assuming it didn't corrupt the data before sending).

Comment: @jtahlborn agreed. Thanks for the clarification. For future readers, this is anyway a niche coincidence that happens to work.